# Listen to location access disable/enable in settings

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcast

In Android OS, in "**Settings**" --> "**Location services**", there is a toggle button named "**Access to my location**" which can be used to disable & enable location info access from apps.

Currently, I am developing a location service application. I am wondering, how can I listen to this setting in my Android project? Is there any broadcast receiver I can use to know right away when user disable or enable "**Access to my location**" ?

If there isn't any broadcast receiver for it, how can I listen to this change in my Android project?

Comment: @ GrlsHu, no, I don't want to do that. The key point of my question is how to listen to this location access setting.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20673766/1994950 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/23756293/1994950 will help

Answer (score 6):

This works for me:

Add receiver to the Manifest file:

```
<receiver
        android:name="com.eegeo.location.LocationProviderChangedReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.location.PROVIDERS_CHANGED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Check both location providers in receiver:

```
public class LocationProviderChangedReceiver  extends BroadcastReceiver{

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        boolean anyLocationProv = false;
        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) MyMainActivity.context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        anyLocationProv |= locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        anyLocationProv |=  locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

        Log.i("", "Location service status" + anyLocationProv);


    }

}
```

Though this receiver is called more than once due to obvious reasons, but this will tell you the status.

Comment: The manifest broadcast receiver should be used only if the app needs location in the background. It should use a runtime broadcast receiver otherwise

Comment: This won't work if your app targets Android 8.0 (API level 26) or above: [Registering broadcast receivers for implicit broadcasts in the manifest has been disabled](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background#broadcasts)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it much simpler this way.  In your BroadcastReceiver's **onReceive()** method:

```
    ContentResolver contentResolver = getContext().getContentResolver();
    // Find out what the settings say about which providers are enabled
    int mode = Settings.Secure.getInt(
            contentResolver, Settings.Secure.LOCATION_MODE, Settings.Secure.LOCATION_MODE_OFF);

    if (mode == Settings.Secure.LOCATION_MODE_OFF) {
        // Location is turned OFF!
    } else {
        // Location is turned ON!
    }
```

~Thanks to this code: [LocationManagerTest.java](http://androidxref.com/5.1.0_r1/xref/cts/tests/tests/location/src/android/location/cts/LocationManagerTest.java)

Comment: To all: this was valid then. Today, all of this is deprecated.

Comment: @VonSchnauzer what's the current solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code to check whether Location Service Enable or not

```
 LocationManager lm = null;
 boolean gps_enabled,network_enabled;
    if(lm==null)
        lm = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    try{
    gps_enabled = lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    }catch(Exception ex){}
    try{
    network_enabled = lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
    }catch(Exception ex){}

   if(!gps_enabled && !network_enabled){
        dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        dialog.setMessage(context.getResources().getString(R.string.gps_network_not_enabled));
        dialog.setPositiveButton(context.getResources().getString(R.string.open_location_settings), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface paramDialogInterface, int paramInt) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent myIntent = new Intent( Settings.ACTION_SECURITY_SETTINGS );
                context.startActivity(myIntent);
                //get gps
            }
        });
        dialog.setNegativeButton(context.getString(R.string.Cancel), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface paramDialogInterface, int paramInt) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
        dialog.show();

    }
```

Comment: Hi, my question is not about how to check the value, but about how to listen to the change, meaning that how to get a notification in code that user has changed this location access in settings & then get the changed value.

Comment: @GrIsHu That is incorrect.  Have you tried usman's solution below?

Answer (score 0):

2023: This solution listens to, and reacts, when user toggles the location in curtain menu. The hard part was figuring out which "intent" filter  flag to use (`LocationManager.PROVIDERS_CHANGED_ACTION`).

In my example I use `@Inject constructor` (Hilt). If you don't, then just send the `context` as parameter to `register()` and `unregister()`: `register(context: Context)` etc.

An extension on Context:

```
fun Context.isLocationEnabled(): Boolean {
  val locationManager = this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE) as LocationManager
  return LocationManagerCompat.isLocationEnabled(locationManager)
}
```

Create a BroadcastReceiver:

```
class LocationBroadcastReceiver @Inject constructor(private val context: Context) : BroadcastReceiver() {

  private val locationStateChange: BehaviorRelay<Boolean> = BehaviorRelay.createDefault(context.isLocationEnabled())

  override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
    val action = intent.action

    if (action == LocationManager.PROVIDERS_CHANGED_ACTION) {
      val state = context.isLocationEnabled()
      locationStateChange.accept(state)
    }
  }

  fun subscribeState(): Flowable<Boolean> {
    return locationStateChange.toFlowable(BackpressureStrategy.LATEST)
  }

  /**
  * Listen to subscribeState() to receive updates
  */
  fun register() {
    val filter = IntentFilter(LocationManager.PROVIDERS_CHANGED_ACTION)
    val receiverFlags = ContextCompat.RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED
    ContextCompat.registerReceiver(context, this, filter, receiverFlags)
  }

  fun unregister() {
    context.unregisterReceiver(this)
  }

}
```

Now you can subscribe to

```
subscribeState()
```

from your viewModel or compose class and do what you must.