# How to trigger broadcast receiver when gps is turn on/off?

Tags: android, gps, broadcastreceiver, location-provider

```
public class BootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver  {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().matches("android.location.PROVIDERS_CHANGED")) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "in android.location.PROVIDERS_CHANGED",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent pushIntent = new Intent(context, LocalService.class);
            context.startService(pushIntent);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(context, "not in android.location.PROVIDERS_CHANGED",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent pushIntent = new Intent(context, LocalService.class);
            context.startService(pushIntent);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location arg0) {

    }
}
```

In my app , i need to  trigger broadcast receiver when gps is turn on/off.
 look into the matter and suggest best one to implement in app.

Comment: Are you trying to listen for setting of Location mode: 
'Device only (Use GPS to determine your location)'?

Answer (score 76, accepted):

This is useful when user want to trigger any action on turn On/Off location provides

You should add this action in manifest

```
<action android:name="android.location.PROVIDERS_CHANGED" />
```

and after add this action you can trigger your broadcast receiver

```
<receiver android:name=".GpsLocationReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.location.PROVIDERS_CHANGED" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

And in your `BroadcastReceiver` class you have to implement `LocationListener` in that class which is given following below..

```
public class GpsLocationReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {        
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().matches("android.location.PROVIDERS_CHANGED")) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "in android.location.PROVIDERS_CHANGED",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent pushIntent = new Intent(context, LocalService.class);
            context.startService(pushIntent);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have any solution for screen rotation broadcast receiver???????? please help

Comment: Why do i need to implement LocationListener here?

Comment: @Kartihkraj... No there is no need to implement LocationListener here.. I have edited this now.

Comment: @AndroidGuru How does this code tell you if Location mode is on/off?

Comment: Where to add <action android:name="android.location.PROVIDERS_CHANGED" /> other than Intent filter of broadcast receiver

Comment: How to know location turned OFF/ON ?

Answer (score 42):

I want to add **@Deepak Gupta** [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20673766/2949612).
I want to add code for how to register a dynamic brodacsast receiver in your **fragment** or **activity** when GPS status changed.

Register your broadcast receiver as below in your activity or fragment.

```
private BroadcastReceiver gpsReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().matches(LocationManager.PROVIDERS_CHANGED_ACTION)) {
            //Do your stuff on GPS status change
        }
    }
};
```

For **fragment**:

```
getContext().registerReceiver(gpsReceiver, new IntentFilter(LocationManager.PROVIDERS_CHANGED_ACTION));
```

For **activity**:

```
registerReceiver(gpsReceiver, new IntentFilter(LocationManager.PROVIDERS_CHANGED_ACTION));
```

This can be used any place where you have access to a Context, not just inside an activity or fragment. I hope its helps.

Comment: No need to hard-code the action string. Instead use `...matches(LocationManager.PROVIDERS_CHANGED_ACTION)` and `...new IntentFilter(LocationManager.PROVIDERS_CHANGED_ACTION)`

Comment: Thanks @tir38, I have updated my answer with `LocationManager.PROVIDERS_CHANGED_ACTION`

Comment: What is registerReceiver? @pRaNaY

Comment: It is an activity method which use to register BroadcastReceiver. Check https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html

Comment: Is this still working?, I can't seems to be getting Broadcast on LocationManager.PROVIDERS_CHANGED_ACTION

Comment: Using this We cannot know whether it was turned on or off

Comment: How to know location turned OFF/ON ?

Answer (score 14):

You can try this code, as user @DanielNugent pointed out:

```
    ContentResolver contentResolver = getContext().getContentResolver();
    // Find out what the settings say about which providers are enabled
    int mode = Settings.Secure.getInt(
            contentResolver, Settings.Secure.LOCATION_MODE, Settings.Secure.LOCATION_MODE_OFF);

    if (mode != Settings.Secure.LOCATION_MODE_OFF) {
      if (mode == Settings.Secure.LOCATION_MODE_HIGH_ACCURACY) {
        locationMode = "High accuracy. Uses GPS, Wi-Fi, and mobile networks to determine location";
      } else if (mode == Settings.Secure.LOCATION_MODE_SENSORS_ONLY) {
          locationMode = "Device only. Uses GPS to determine location";
      } else if (mode == Settings.Secure.LOCATION_MODE_BATTERY_SAVING) {
          locationMode = "Battery saving. Uses Wi-Fi and mobile networks to determine location";
      }
    }
```

Comment: Your answer works great, but it works only for Android API version 19 and above. Is there a way for versions lower than 19?

Comment: That setting constants were deprecated in API level 28.

Answer (score 0):

**Working solution after Android location modes are introduced in Android**

We can check with location mode for more accurate

```
private boolean isGpsEnabled(Context context) {
            ContentResolver contentResolver = getContext().getContentResolver();
            // Find out what the settings say about which providers are enabled
            //  String locationMode = "Settings.Secure.LOCATION_MODE_OFF";
            int mode = Settings.Secure.getInt(
                    contentResolver, Settings.Secure.LOCATION_MODE, Settings.Secure.LOCATION_MODE_OFF);
            if (mode != Settings.Secure.LOCATION_MODE_OFF) {
                return true;
               /* if (mode == Settings.Secure.LOCATION_MODE_HIGH_ACCURACY) {
                    locationMode = "High accuracy. Uses GPS, Wi-Fi, and mobile networks to determine location";
                } else if (mode == Settings.Secure.LOCATION_MODE_SENSORS_ONLY) {
                    locationMode = "Device only. Uses GPS to determine location";
                } else if (mode == Settings.Secure.LOCATION_MODE_BATTERY_SAVING) {
                    locationMode = "Battery saving. Uses Wi-Fi and mobile networks to determine location";
                }*/
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score -3):

you can try this

**Manifest**

```
<receiver android:name=".MyReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.location.GPS_ENABLED_CHANGE" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

**MyReceiver**

```
if (intent.getAction().matches("android.location.GPS_ENABLED_CHANGE"))
    {
        boolean enabled = intent.getBooleanExtra("enabled",false);

        Toast.makeText(context, "GPS : " + enabled,
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Comment: `Intent` is always null. Dose not contain anything like `enabled`.