# Why does Broadcast Receiver never get called?

Tags: android, events, gps, broadcastreceiver

Inside my **MainActivity** I am creating a receiver and sending a broadcast:

```
GPSStartedReceiver receiver = new GPSStartedReceiver();
this.registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter("android.location.GPS_ENABLED_CHANGE"));
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction("com.test.broadcastReceiver.GPSStartedReceiver()");
sendBroadcast(intent);
```

But when I enable my **GPS**, the broadcast receiver is not being called.

Below is the part of the receiver in the **Manifest**:

```
<receiver android:name="com.test.broadcastReceiver.GPSStartedReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.location.GPS_ENABLED_CHANGE" />
        </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

And the **Broadcast Receiver**:

```
    public class GPSStartedReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    // Start service 5 seconds after GPS is enabled
    private static final long WAIT_TIME = 1000 * 5;
    // Restart service every 30 seconds
    private static final long REPEAT_TIME = 1000 * 30;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {

        if (intent.getAction().equals("android.location.GPS_ENABLED_CHANGE")) {

            final Handler handler = new Handler();

            Toast.makeText(context,
                    context.getResources().getString(R.string.starting_in_5),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    AlarmManager service = (AlarmManager) context
                            .getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
                    Intent i = new Intent(context, GPSTracker.class);
                    PendingIntent pending = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, i,
                            PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
                    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                    // Start 30 seconds after boot completed
                    cal.add(Calendar.SECOND, 30);
                    // Fetch every 30 seconds
                    service.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                            cal.getTimeInMillis(), REPEAT_TIME, pending);
                }
            }, WAIT_TIME);

        }
    }
}
```

Why does the receiver never get called, even though I enable my **GPS**?

Comment: Not understand. Do you want to trigger something when gps gets enable/disable???

Comment: @Clairvoyant Yes! And GPSStartedReceiver() never gets called!

Comment: Can you how your broadcast receiver class code

Comment: @Clairvoyant I have edited the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **PROVIDERS_CHANGED_ACTION** Added in API level 9 Broadcast intent action when the configured location providers change. For use with isProviderEnabled(String). If you're interacting with the LOCATION_MODE API, use MODE_CHANGED_ACTION instead.

Constant Value: "android.location.PROVIDERS_CHANGED"

You can find your solution on [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20673766/2715073)

Comment: This answer is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried registering a BroadcastReceiver for listening to Intent Action `PROVIDERS_CHANGED_ACTION` ? If this does not work, you can get an instance of locationManager and then register a GpsStatusListener as follows `mLocationManager.addGpsStatusListener(new android.location.GpsStatus.Listener())` to it and use its internal methods.

Hope it helps

Comment: Glad it helped. Please mark it as solved if done. Cheers!