# In FCM trying to get a latitude and longitude of a person, wherever he/she get a notification to him/her in android

Tags: android, push-notification, location

I am using FCM and getting a notification too, in that trying to get a latitude and longitude of a person, wherever he or she gets a notification to him or her without entering an application in android but getting 0.0 in **latitude and longitude**.

I am not done anything in MainActivity because get a location in the background and send that to a server

**Below is my MyFirebaseMessagingService code:**

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService implements PowerConnectionReciever.BatteryCallback 
{

LocationTrack locationTrack;
private double longitude,latitude;
Context context=this;
IntentFilter intentfilter;
private PowerConnectionReciever powerConnectionReciever=new 
PowerConnectionReciever();
private String batterystatus;
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    // ...


    Log.wtf(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());

    // Check if message contains a data payload.
    if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
        Log.wtf(TAG, "Message data payload: " + remoteMessage.getData());

        if (/* Check if data needs to be processed by long-running job */ true) {
            // For long-running tasks (10 seconds or more) use Firebase Job Dispatcher.
           // scheduleJob();

        } else {
            // Handle message within 10 seconds
           // handleNow();

        }

    }

    // Check if message contains a notification payload.
    if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
        Log.wtf(TAG, "Message Notification Body: " + 
         remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
        Log.wtf("Status","Message arrived");
        intentfilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED);
        locationTrack = new LocationTrack(context);

        if (locationTrack.canGetLocation()) {

            longitude = locationTrack.getLongitude();
            latitude = locationTrack.getLatitude();

            context.registerReceiver(powerConnectionReciever, intentfilter);

            Toast.makeText(this, "Locatin"+latitude+","+locationTrack, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {

            locationTrack.showSettingsAlert();
        }


    }

    // Also if you intend on generating your own notifications as a result of a received FCM
    // message, here is where that should be initiated. See sendNotification method below.
}

@Override
public void batteryInfo(boolean isCharging, boolean status, int percent) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Longitude:" + Double.toString(longitude) + "\nLatitude:" + Double.toString(latitude) + "\nBattery status:" + percent+"%", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    batterystatus = "isCharging: " + isCharging + "\n" + "\n" +
            "isCharged:" + status + "\n" + "\n" +
            "Percent: " + percent + "\n";

    Log.wtf("BStatus", batterystatus);
    }
   }
```

---

**LocationTrack Class code:**

```
public class LocationTrack extends Service implements LocationListener {

private final Context mContext;
boolean checkGPS = false;
boolean checkNetwork = false;
boolean canGetLocation = false;
Location loc;
double latitude;
double longitude;
private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 10;
private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 1000 * 60 * 1;
protected LocationManager locationManager;

public LocationTrack(Context mContext) {
    this.mContext = mContext;
    getLocation(mContext);
}

private Location getLocation(Context mContext) {

    try {
        locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext
                .getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

        // get GPS status
        checkGPS = locationManager
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

        // get network provider status
        checkNetwork = locationManager
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

        if (!checkGPS && !checkNetwork) {
            Toast.makeText(mContext, "No Service Provider is available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            this.canGetLocation = true;

            // if GPS Enabled get lat/long using GPS Services
            if (checkGPS) {

                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(mContext, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(mContext, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    // TODO: Consider calling
                    //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
                    // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                    //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                    //                                          int[] grantResults)
                    // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                    // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
                }
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                        LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                        MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                        MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                if (locationManager != null) {
                    loc = locationManager
                            .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                    if (loc != null) {
                        latitude = loc.getLatitude();
                        longitude = loc.getLongitude();
                    }
                }


            }


            if (checkNetwork) {

                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(mContext, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(mContext, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    // TODO: Consider calling
                    //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
                    // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                    //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                    //                                          int[] grantResults)
                    // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                    // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
                }
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                        LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                        MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                        MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);

                if (locationManager != null) {
                    loc = locationManager
                            .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

                }

                if (loc != null) {
                    latitude = loc.getLatitude();
                    longitude = loc.getLongitude();
                }
            }

        }


    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return loc;
}

public double getLongitude() {
    if (loc != null) {
        longitude = loc.getLongitude();
    }
    return longitude;
}

public double getLatitude() {
    if (loc != null) {
        latitude = loc.getLatitude();
    }
        return latitude;
}

public boolean canGetLocation() {
    return this.canGetLocation;
}

public void showSettingsAlert() {
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);


    alertDialog.setTitle("GPS is not Enabled!");

    alertDialog.setMessage("Do you want to turn on GPS?");


    alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
            mContext.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });


    alertDialog.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });


    alertDialog.show();
}


public void stopListener() {
    if (locationManager != null) {

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(mContext, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(mContext, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }
        locationManager.removeUpdates(LocationTrack.this);
    }
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {

}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {

}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {

}
}
```

Comment: take help from this answer just go throw it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46321106/after-enable-gps-from-an-app-prompt-how-to-refresh-and-get-the-current-location/46321722#46321722

Comment: Hi vishal, like you said I can get a location but my requirement is getting lat and lng without human intervention, without going to an app I should get a lat and lng, when the notification gets to arrive at a handset and in the background only have to send lat and lng to sever.  Hope you will understand what i am saying.!

Comment: @ManjunathNarasannavar Are you sending **data only** message when app is in background?

Comment: @global_warming No I have to send a lat and lng to a server but in that code I am not sending to a server because latitude and longitude is getting 0.0

Comment: Are you getting lat-long when app is in foreground?

Comment: @global_warming Yes but my requirement is once a notification gets into a handset, without any user interaction, has to get a lat and lng of a notification where a user gets received

Comment: Are you sending FCM message from firebase console?

Comment: @global_warming Yes for testing I am sending through FCM console

Answer (score 0):

Reason why you aren't getting lat-long when app is in background:
**-->>** You are Sending message from Firebase console
**-->>** Message contains notification payload.
**-->>** If app is in background, [FCM notification is displayed in notification tray but `onMessageReceived()` is not called](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive#handling_messages) and it never fetches lat-long from `LocationTrack`.
**-->>** Results into 0.0

The solution is to send [**data only**](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#notifications_and_data_messages) FCM message from server as you can't send data only message from Firebase Console. In that case `onMessageReceived()` will be called even when app is in background.

If you want to send data only payload to particular device id, send JSON like:

```
{ 
 "message":
     { 
      "token":"yourDeviceToken",
      "data":
          {      
           "keyFoo":"valueBar"   
          },
       "android":
          {
           "priority":"high"
           "ttl":"3600s"
          }
     }
}
```

Comment: Oops..! Thank for the solution, I'll try it and let's come back to you.!

Comment: I am using "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send" URL and getting a response: {
    "message_id": 570327904788888888
} but notification is not coming to devices. what would be the issue?

Comment: are you sending data only? can you post json you are sending from server?

Comment: Yes, {
  "to":"/topics/testdata",
  "data": {
    "message":"Test msg"
  }
}

Comment: Are you getting this in app?

Comment: And one more thing whenever I am sending to particular device, it is showing error like this: {
    "multicast_id": 6674088888888888888,
    "success": 0,
    "failure": 1,
    "canonical_ids": 0,
    "results": [
        {
            "error": "MismatchSenderId"
        }
    ]
}

Comment: Nope, in postman Body i am sending like this { "to":"/topics/testdata", "data": { "message":"Test msg" } }, for this i am getting response too, this is response { "message_id": 570327904788888888 } but notification is not coming to devices

Comment: you won't get notification in this case, check device log for incoming data payload.

Comment: Then there must be some error in server side implementation

Comment: If there is an error then it will not give a proper response like this{ "message_id": 570327904788888888 }, it may give some error response, So don't know what would be the error exactly.

Comment: Getting response like this " Expected 'r' instead of 'o' "

Comment: How do we find whether a app is gets called onMessageReceived in background or killed?

Comment: Firebase SDK will manage that even if app is killed(not force stop), you can see logs will appear in logcat.

Comment: I am sending notification data from POSTMAN, there I am getting acknowledgment but the notification is not coming to devices, But Sending notification from FCM console getting FCM notification to devices.

Comment: When an app is open, FCM notification is not coming to a device but in the log, i can see the details of the notification.

Comment: Try sending high priority message. Which phone are you using for testing?

Comment: I have edited json data for high priority, check that

Comment: Below devices which I am testing my app:Panasonic T44 and Coolpad Note

Comment: I am not able to receive the notification

Comment: I am using the local notification to cross-check whether an onMessageReceived getting called or not, but whenever an app is open then I am getting a local notification, when the app is in the background or killed not getting that local notification, I don't know what is going on????

Comment: You don't get notifications in case of data-only message, you have to check logcat. Try testing on different devices.