# when user turn On location show marker on current location

Tags: java, android, google-maps

i create one map in this i show one marker on current location its working fine
when location turn on already but when Activity is on and i turn On location it does not show any marker i want to show marker when location is on 
any help?..

```
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
         getCurrentLocation();
       // latLngCurrentLocation is my current location which is update using getCurrentLocation() method.

    if(latLngCurrentLocation != null) {

    // add marker on current location
            markerCurrent = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(latLngCurrentLocation)
                    .draggable(true)
                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN))
                    .title("Current Location"));

            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLngCurrentLocation));
            mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(8));
            mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
            mMap.setOnMarkerDragListener(this);


        }

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You will get location in `onLocationChanged(Location location)` once your position is changed. You will get Latitude and Longitude in `location` object, so you can set your marker into `onLocationChanged(Location location)` method

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location)
{
    mLastLocation = location;
    if (mCurrLocationMarker != null)
    {
        mCurrLocationMarker.remove();
    }

    //Place current location marker
    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
    MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
    markerOptions.position(latLng);
    markerOptions.title("Current Position");
    markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_ORANGE));
    mCurrLocationMarker = mGoogleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);

    //move map camera
    mGoogleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
    mGoogleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(11));


}
```

OR if you want to refresh your marker once GPS turns on then you can use `BroadcastReceiver`. BroadcastReciever triggers when GPS turns/off so you can check whether GPS is turned on or off, You can find example in following link, [Broadcast receiver for GPS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20673766/5237917)

Comment: thanks for your quick reply but i really want that without using OnLocation change method

Comment: post your `getCurrentMethod()` code @nileshprajapati

Comment: its method for get current Location there where i only used  Location location = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(googleApiClient);

Comment: You can use timer for that. You need to get function from particular time interval. @nileshprajapati

Comment: using timer i can method more time its not good for app its consume more memory and   battery  also .

Comment: is there i get any trigger when location turn on/off ?

Comment: That's why Location API introduced. You shoud use` FusedLocationAPI`. @nileshprajapati

Comment: its not issue to get current location issue is that after turn on location Refresh map

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160511/discussion-between-kulsdroid-and-nilesh-prajapati). @nileshprajapati

Comment: @nileshPrajapati onLocationChanged() is what you need as this way you can place a marker without any timer or handler as onLocationChanged will automatically be called when the location is updated which depends on Internet Speed as your 10 sec timer may work on fast internet connection but will not work on a slow connection which takes 1-2 minutes to load the location. So conclusively, onLocationChanged() will work exactly the way you want.

Comment: OnLocationChange() not trigger quickly for that user need to change there location and  i don't want that @LalitSinghFauzdar

Comment: `onLocationChanged()` is called automatically after some specified delay (mostly 10 sec) after loading the initial location without even change in the physical location. Also, instead of using it, you only have the handler left for getting what you want. Just initialize a handler with 5 sec and re-call it unlit the location Latlng is not null.

Answer (score 2):

Through GpsTracker class or googleClient api you can get latitude and longtitude and then get it as gpstracker.getlatitude and getlongtitude and set this values to global variables and access it whereever you want.

Comment: is there i get any trigger when location turn on/off ?

Comment: Cant get your question.

Comment: if user turn On his location any default method or anything else which is trigger from that we can identify user turn on/off location

Comment: you need to add a dialog that asks users to turn on gps everytime if gps if off.Please refer to the link
[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4721449/how-can-i-enable-or-disable-the-gps-programmatically-on-android)

Comment: i  all ready done this thing for tun on location but after turn on location i come back to map app there where no marker is added for that i need close app and restart it to see marker but i don"t want to do that @Shivam