# Detecting GPS on/off in Android Oreo (API26+)

Tags: android, gps, broadcastreceiver, android-8.0-oreo

I have service for location update and detect GPS ON/OFF state by BroadcastReceiver (for example here is code https://stackoverflow.com/a/20673766/9177782). It works fine for API25 and less.
But what I should use for API26+ ? This BroadcastReceiver doesn't work for API26+ because of restriction of Oreo. I need to detect GPS OFF state by my foreground location service

Comment: Did you got your answer? I'm looking for same answer

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcast-exceptions.html
Following implicit broadcast receiver  is supported

Comment: @Rahul Thanks mate! I will try it. This brodcast should be working: ACTION_LOCALE_CHANGED
    Only sent when the locale changes, which is not often. Apps might need to update their data when the locale changes.

Comment: Are you looking for broadcast after app is closed?

Comment: @moDev Yes, I am looking for broadcast after app is closed.

Comment: @A.M.  Did you get an answer? I'm also looking for the same

Comment: I have the same problem. Looks like we're gonna have to use context registered receivers : https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts#context-registered-receivers